# Beginner questions: how to use these obscure commands like 'RenderWindow' in C++

Tags: c++, header-files

This is kind of a beginner question, so please let me know if this is appropriate for this website and if not, where else I should be asking this.

I've just gotten into the basics of C++ (pretty much what's being taught in this video from FreeCodeCamp: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLnPwxZdW4Y). Obviously, not everything there is to know is discussed in this tutorial and I've been running into a couple of things in other demonstration vids that I don't quite get yet.

For example, this quick demonstration of how Tetris can be coded: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zH_omFPqMO4&t=0m25s) you can see him use the command 'RenderWindow', which apparently creates a new window the size of his choice (320*480 pixels in this case). This doesn't seem to be a standard function in C++, so I assume he somehow imported it. How can I do this myself? Does it have to with the file inclusions written at the top of the file (#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>)? If so, how can I learn more about such files, where can I find them (is it anything like the Python Package Index, or interfaces in Java) and can I create them myself? Any general explanatory words on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please make your posts self contained. Any relevant code should be included directly in the body of the question.

Comment: The function `RenderWindow` is not part of the *standard* C++ language.  You'll have to read the library's documentation on how to use the `RenderWindow` function.

Comment: I recommend typing "RenderWindow C++" into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 3):

> This doesn't seem to be a standard function in C++

That is correct. There are no functions for graphics nor window handling in C++.

> so I assume he somehow imported it. How can I do this myself?

Usually, you would pick a library of your choice (there are many), or do it yourself by using whatever API your operating system provides.

> Does it have to with the file inclusions written at the top of the file (`#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`)?

Yes, SFML is one of those libraries.

> If so, how can I learn more about such files

You would go to the library's homepage and read the documentation.

> where can I find them

Try searching the web for lists of libraries, articles, projects, etc.

> is it anything like the Python Package Index

No, there is no standard one for C++. There are several package managers, build systems, etc. Popular libraries are in most of them and support one or more build systems.

Comment: Note when searching on the web for documentation and tutorials, first carefully search for domain experts in the field and use they resources they recommend. If you just blindly search for information and take what comes, you could find yourself following the teachings of an idiot or raving madman.